# Sharepoint 2010 List attachments display issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am using following code to display the list item attachments in the "All Items" view for a list.

```
 <td id="ItemAttchment{$ID}{generate-id()}" class="ms-vb" style="width: 92px">
          <xsl:element name="SharePoint:AttachmentsField">
          <xsl:attribute name="runat">server</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="FieldName">Attachments</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ControlMode">Display</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Visible">true</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="ItemId">
              <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
 </td>
```

The issue I am facing is

1. SharePoint attachment display does not update the attachment name on the list, If the attachment is changed for that list item later.
2. If I sort the list, the attachments does not get sorted and show up for wrong list items.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue and what would be causing it?

Comment: code is missing

Comment: Found code! ;) @anuja